# Dynamic array of pointers on rows in C#

Tags: c#

I'm very new to the C#, but need to write the following program.
Сlass Matrix with dynamic array of pointers on rows.
Tried to initialize it in constructor with new, but don't understand how to describe it in class. Obviously, I'm getting:

> Cannot implicitly convert type double[] to double[*,*]

```
class Matrix
{
    int rows, cols;
    public double[,] m; //What should I write here?

    public Matrix() 
    {
        rows = 0;
        cols = 0;
    }

    public Matrix(int rows, int cols)
    {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        this.m = new double[rows];
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            this.m[i] = new double[cols];
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                this.m[i, j] = r.Next(0, 1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try `this.m = new double[rows,cols];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different types of two dimensional arrays.  One is defined as [][] and the other as [,].  You are confusing the two unfortunately in your code.

In your case, you would define your array only once.

```
this.m = new double[rows, cols];
```

Comment: There's never a single mention of a `[][]` or jagged-array in the question, not sure where you got that idea from

Comment: The code as written implies a jagged array, despite it being initialized otherwise.  This coding convention is used for a jagged array:  this.m[i] = new double[cols], which the code doesn't have

Comment: Yes, John Kane, you are right. Needed a jagged array. Thank you.